# changing list of strings to atoms using maplist?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, partial-application, maplist

How to change string to atoms using maplist.

This does not work :

```
 ?- maplist(atom_string,["a","b","c"]).
```

first because atom_string/2 has arity of two (How do you do partial-function//currying in prolog).

But even if partial-fun worked the complication is that the first argument of atom_string is the unknown i.e. the call is :

```
  atom_string(A,"atom")
```

not :

```
  atom_string("atom",A)
```

---

this worked :

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- F = \Y^X^(atom_string(X,Y)), maplist(F,["a","b","c"],L).
F = \Y^X^atom_string(X, Y),
L = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: correct ... i asked for changing "strings" to "atoms" using maplist, not "string" to "atom" ... changed the header to be more clear

Comment: Why do you think `atom_string(A, "atom")` is a problem? [SWI-Prolog's documentation for atom_string/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_string/2) says that it's bidirectional, and running the query `?- atom_string(A, "atom").` I get the expected answer `A = atom.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as intended:

```
?- maplist(atom_string, Atoms, ["a","b","c"]).
Atoms = [a, b, c].
```

If this is not what you are after, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper predicate.

```
string_atom(String,Atom) :-
    atom_string(Atom,String).
```

Then run using

```
?- maplist(string_atom,["a","b","c"],Atoms).
Atoms = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: Why would you do that? What is wrong with `maplist(atom_string, Atoms, Strings)`?

Comment: @TA_intern: *Why would you do that?* To avoid leftover choice points in systems with only first argument indexing, e.g. SICStus.

Comment: @false It sounds like a workaround to me. I try to teach my students to fix things _in the right place_, **if possible**. I know there is never agreement what is the right place, and "possible" is on some scale of "very easy" to "theoretically not impossible".

Comment: @TA_intern: It is a pure workaround for systems that need it. Contrast this to other "optimizations" that cut away choice points giving up relational properties.